# Ambiguity in the center of the locus of $|z-z_o|=r$

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

Let $z_o$ be a fixed complex number and $z$ be a variable complex number

I've been told that the locus of $z$ in  $|z-z_o|=r$ where $r\gt0$ is a circle centred at $z_o$

I have not been able to understand this . $z-z_o$ is a complex number originating at the origin so shouldn't the locus be centred at the origin ??

Comment: $|z-z_0|$ gives the distance between points $(x,y)$ and $(x_0,y_0)$. Ergo, the set of $(x,y)$ such that $|z-z_0|=r$ is a circle of radius $r$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convince yourself by studying the real case $|x-5|=1$ for instance.

Similarly $x-5$ is a real originating at the origin, yet $x=4\text{ or }6$ both points at distance $1$ of center $5$.

The complex case is just the two dimensional extension of the real case.

Comment: Thank you sir/ma'am helped alot !